# What is the MapFragment's cache expiry(google maps android api)

Tags: android, google-maps, caching, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to figure out cache expiry headers for the map rendered in android map fragment. As i see google has a policy for it's own map app's offline access for 30 days. What would be the expiry period for cache through " Maps Android API".

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the 30 days you've mentioned found [here](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?hl=en&rd=2), Android Maps API seems to be silent about offline maps expiry periods. However [this tutorial](http://datamoil.blogspot.com/2011/05/offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid.html) states that using OSMDroid, you can set the maps cache expiry period as long as 10 years.